# How to fix CSRF error on logging in using REST API in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I am beginner to Django, following [this](https://studygyaan.com/django/django-rest-framework-tutorial-register-login-logout) tutorial to implement register, login and logout using DRF. The register is working fine, but I am not able to login using postman, it is showing CSRF error. Already tried using @csrf_exempt decorator, but then it is showing AttributeError on LoginAPI.asView()

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; color:#000; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>


  <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.</p>

</div>

<div id="info">
  <h2>Help</h2>
    
    <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
    <pre>
    CSRF cookie not set.
    </pre>
    

  <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
  <a
  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/">Django's
  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>

    <li>The view function passes a <code>request</code> to the template's <a
    href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render"><code>render</code></a>
    method.</li>

    <li>In the template, there is a <code>{% csrf_token
    %}</code> template tag inside each POST form that
    targets an internal URL.</li>

    <li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use
    <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code>
    template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>

    <li>The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser
    tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the
    page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.</li>
  </ul>

  <p>You're seeing the help section of this page because you have <code>DEBUG =
  True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>,
  and only the initial error message will be displayed.  </p>

  <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the main problem is, when you want to use login API don't use slash in your url and in your request.

I have got answer with this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30624172)

Answer (score 0):

According the error:

> AttributeError: el objeto 'función' no tiene atributo 'as_view'

... Either the View is not a class-based view or if it is, you should aggregate the `method_decorator` to be able to use the `csrf_exempt` decorator, because this last one only works in function-based views.

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='method_name')
def View():
```